# jquery slideToggle keeps closing parent UL when child LI is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I stop the parent UL from closing when a child LI is clicked? For example, if you click on make1 the child UL will slide open. Then if you click on 1 model1 the child UL opens but the parent UL closes. If giving a fiddle link to see the broken code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('li.menu-item-type-custom').on('click', function () {

        $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[Sample broken code](https://jsfiddle.net/k4eLc5o1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoy just need stop event bubbling up on parent element which is under the same event. Try stopPropogation() like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('li.menu-item-type-custom').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).children('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j331o3wy/